# impresión sin vista previa en Crystal Reports y ReportViewer

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer, crystal-reports

Tengo un proyecto en donde creé dos reportes uno por `Crystal Report` y otro por `ReportViewer`, la pregunta es ¿Cuál sería la línea de código para mandar imprimir directamente sin que me muestre un previo? O sea una impresión directa.

Comment: Puedes agregar una parte de tu código? De otra manera esto puede a dar a respuestas muy abiertas que no resuelvan tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Crystal Report` puedes enviar la impresion directa usando el metodo `PrintToPrinter` del document

[ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691452(v=vs.71).aspx)

`Reporting Service` por medio de `ReportViewer` no veo una impresion directa, pero si hay alternativa exportando el reporte

[Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx)

enviarias la imagen a la impresora usando el PrintDocument